# How to use authenticated user data inside the application

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a long time. I have read courses about PHP sessions and I had proposals to use localstorage but to no avail

**The problem:**

Im working with angularJS and PHP backend, and I have 2 views, one 'login.html' and the other 'info.html', 2 controllers (one for the login function and the other for selecting the user's data) . I managed to do the authentication phase but for the second step I want that when the user authenticates, it will be redirected to other view (info.html) where all the information of this user will be displayed. How can I store the data from login function and use it in the second controller(second web service)

**login.php**

```
 <?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["naam"] = $Email; 
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  } 
       $result['code'] = 603;
       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';


$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

**loginCtrl**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

**infoCtrl :**

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter){

    $scope.loadColis = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/info.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data;  
           });
      }
```

**info.php**

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM client where ???" ;
....
```

I don't know how get user authenticated data, how can I do please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a "Token" and save it on server-side (database) and in $_SESSION or in a cookie (client-side)

That way, everytime you do a php request you can check the session/cookie.

**info.php**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
```

**login.php**

Token should be unique and different everytime your clients logs in.

```
$token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
$query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE email = '".$Email."'";
mysqli_query($connect , $query);
```

So your login.php could look something like this..

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
$token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
    $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE email = '".$Email."'";
    mysqli_query($connect , $query);

       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $_SESSION["naam"] = $Email; 
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  } 
       $result['code'] = 603;
       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';


$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

I hope I didn't miss anything. :)

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do your suggestion but I get this error in the info.php file, saying that token is not definded

Answer (score 0):

As good practice, you can create token:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
   ...
   $result['token'] = ...Generate some random string...
   $result['token'] = $token;
   mysqli_query($connect , "INSERT INTO tokens set token = $token and email = $Email");
   ...
```

After that you save this token in cookie and in the info.php you can do something like that:

```
...
$query = "SELECT email FROM tokens WHERE token = $_COOKIE['token']"
...
```

Also you can get information from client table by email if you need.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do your suggestion but I get this error in the info.php file, saying that token is not definded

Comment: Yes, you should create tokens table in mysql. Simplest schema can be like this: 
        CREATE TABLE token (a TEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (token), b TEXT NUT NULL);

Comment: Yes I already create it, but I don't know why I still have this problem: indefinded index token in info.php file, should I add something to this file?

Comment: When I try just a simple select (select * from client), I get all users but when I add (WHERE token = $_COOKIE['token']") I get nothing!

Comment: 1. As I've wrote, you should set token in cookie. For example: setcookie('token', $token);
2. You shouldn't try to select from client by token because I recommend you to add new table. You can add token in same table, but in this case your token will be work only from one place. In this case you can make two queries: select email from tokens table and after that select from clients by email, or you can write sql query with join, for example SELECT *.c FROM tokens t, clients c WHERE t.email = c.email AND t.token = $_COOKIE['token'] (here you must think about sql injection).

Comment: @SalamSalam could you mark my answer as solution if it helped you?

Comment: Im sorry, but Im still working and trying to implement what you suggested, but it doesn't work yet. Thank you

Comment: @SalamSalam what problem do you have?

Comment: Thank you LusemFerre, but I still have the same problem, honestly I tried to understand how to use cookies but I can't solve my problem